# <Error>: ImageIO: readICCData Embedded profile header length is greater than data length

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tableView with plist content. cells contains UIImage and UILabel. When i run this app on simulator i get this error at once.

> : ImageIO: readICCData Embedded profile header length is
>   greater than data length.

can you tell me what this error means and how can i solve it?